# Using symbol before it is definied

Tags: haskell

How is it that in line below on the right side of equation one could use symbol 'fibs' although it is not yet definied:

```
let fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Comment: @NiklasB. I know what is recursion but I do not understand this specific one liner. See my comment under GManNickG answer.

Comment: @NiklasB. Most languages make you jump through a couple of hoops to use a _value_ in its own definition, though. Few have laziness built in.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, true, most languages only support recursion for functions, not for lists.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The point is that the definition of `fibs`

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

is not evaluated until it is used somewhere else. Then the definition unfolds using the already known part. We begin with `fibs = 0 : 1 : ???`. Then if the third element is ever needed, the definition is evaluated one step further,

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) (0 : 1 : ???) (tail (0 : 1 : ???))
     = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) (0 : 1 : ???) (1 : ???)
     = 0 : 1 : (0 + 1) : zipWith (+) (1 : ???) (???)
```

but then the unknown part `???` has become partly known, it has been determined to be `??? = 1 : ????`, so the unfolding can go on,

```
     = 0 : 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) (1 : 1 : ????) (1 : ????)
     = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : zipWith (+) (1 : ????) (????)
     -- now ???? is known to be 2:?????
     = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : zipWith (+) (1 : 2 : ?????) (2 : ?????)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, at first glance it looks more tricky than function recursion. Are there some constraints on the syntax that computes list/values recursively? In other words, but not precesily, what is allowed syntax?

Comment: There are no syntactical restrictions, you just use the value being defined in the expression it's defined as, `value = some expression using value`. The point to watch out for is whether the computation terminates. You could for example try to define `cycle xs = let result = result ++ xs in result`. But if you try to evaluate it, you first have to find out whether `result` is nonempty, to know which equation to use for `(++)`. So you look at the definition of `result`, `result = result ++ xs`, so to find out whether `result` is nonempty, you must find out whether `result` is nonempty ...

Comment: But if you defined it `cycle xs = let result = xs ++ result in result`, you already know enough of `result` not to get stuck when the need of inspecting `result` arises in the computation of `result` (unless `xs` is empty, that would put you in the `let x = x in x` situation). So, such a self-referencing definition requires that some part of `value` can be determined before inspecting it in the defining expression, and the next needed part can always be determined using what is already known.

Answer (score 6):

It won't actually try to call `fibs` in your definition until something else uses `fibs` later on in your program, *at which point `fibs` has been completely defined*.

You can do this in most other languages too:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    if (x <= 0) return 0;

    // will call foo when it gets there, at which point its been defined
    foo(x - 1); 
}
```

Comment: I understand recurence in imperative languages and also in haskell when it is splitted to few lines. e.g fib 0 = 0; fib 1 = 1; fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2). I do not understand way it is used in example I have given in main question.

Comment: @Trismegistos: It's exactly the same, Haskell doesn't need to execute this function until it's called. When you call `fibs` somewhere else, and within that call it reaches `fibs`, it just stat the process over again. Haskell doesn't need to call it or anything while it's being defined/parsed.

Answer (score 4):

*All* Haskell bindings are recursive. This is different than most languages, but it often works correctly due to laziness (Haskell evaluation is non-strict, in contrast to most popular languages). Newbies are often tripped up when they try something like:

```
main = do
  let a = 3
  let a = 3 + a
  print a
```

Because the second binding to `a` actually *ignores and shadows* the first, and defines `a` in terms of itself, which causes an infinite loop when you try to print out the result of `3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + ...`

A simpler example of an infinite list is `ones`: an infinite list of `1`s

```
ones = 1 : ones
```

In this case, ones simply refers to itself

```
   _______
   |     |
   v     |
________ |
| ones | |
| 1 : ---|
--------
```

In Haskell, you can create an infinite tree in much the same way that you can create an infinite list:

```
data Tree a = Stub | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
onesTree = Branch 1 onesTree onesTree


______  _______
|    |  |      |
|    v  v      |
| ____________ |
| | onesTree | |
|--- | 1 | ----|
  ------------
```

I think the real question is: why don't other languages support recursive values as conveniently as Haskell?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to understand this it's good to understand how lazy evaluation is implemented.  Basically, unevaluated expressions are represented by **thunks**: a data structure that represents all of the information needed to calculate the value when it is actually needed.  When the latter happens (or as we say, when the thunk is **forced**), the code to calculate the value is executed, and the thunk's content is replaced with the result—which may have pointers to other thunks.

So `fibs` starts out as a thunk.  This thunk contains pointers to the code that's used to compute its value, and pointers to the thunks that this code takes as arguments.  One of these latter pointers is a pointer to `fibs` itself.